# Empirical quantile definition?

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics, quantile

Suppose we have an order set of data $\mathcal X=\{x^{(1)},x^{(2)},...,x^{(n)}\}$ such that $x^{(1)}\le x^{(2)}\le ...\le x^{(n)}$. For some reason in my course's definition of empirical quantile, we write the probability of getting a value less than $x^{(i)}$ as:

$$
p_i=\frac{i}{n+1}
$$

I don't understand why we divide by $n+1$ instead of $n$, because it means that the probability $p_n$ of getting a value less than the highest value in our data set is *less than 1* (i.e. $p_n=\frac{n}{n+1}<1$). But clearly we should have $p_n=1$? So how come this definition is used for the empirical quantile?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The probability of getting one of the data points in $\chi$ less than $x_{(n)}$ is 1. But the probability of getting a general $X$ less than $x_{(n)}$ is less than 1.

Comment: These $p_i$'s that you mentioned.. are you sure these do not refer only to a particular problem you haven't mentioned? These happen in Uniform certainly, but i do not know of other examples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "... getting a value less than ..." but the expression you show for $p_i$ arises in the context of order statistics as follows.

If the underlying random variable has a uniform distribution, then $p_i = i/(n+1)$ is the expected value of the $i$th order statistic.

The probability that the $i$th order statistic is less than $x$ is the probability of the union of mutually exclusive events where at least $j \geq i$ of the samples are less than $x$ but the remaining $n-j$ samples are greater than $x$. There are ${n}\choose{j}$ different combinations satisfying this condition. The probability of this union is a sum of probabilities over $j=i, \ldots,n$.

Assuming an iid sample of size $n$, the distribution function for $X_{(i)}$ is

$$\mathbb{P} (X_{(i)}\leq x) = \sum_{j=i}^{n} {{n}\choose{j}}[F(x)]^j[1-F(x)]^{n-j}$$

To get the density function, take the derivative of the distribution function with respect to $x$ to obtain

$$f_{(i)}(x) = n{n-1 \choose i-1}F(x)^{i-1}(1-F(x))^{n-i}f(x).$$

Assuming a $U(0,1)$ distribution, we have $f(x) = 1$ and $F(x) = x$.  Integrating the product $xf_{(i)}(x)$ over $[0,1]$ we find the expected value

$$E(X_{(i)})=\frac{i}{n+1}.$$